# Constructing String Without Concatenation in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there any way to place a declared string in between unicode symbols without concatenation?
For example, I have declared a string `a = "house"`.  Is there anyway I can declare `<\house/>` without 
having to result to `"<\\" + a + "/>"` ? Concatenation may become cumbersome when more unicode symbols get involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about string interpolation?

```
"<\\%s/>" % a
```

or for multiple items:

```
<"\\%s %s/>" % (a, b)
```

Also works with dictionaries:

```
"<\\%(a)s/>" % {'a': a}
```

Python 3.x style interpolation is done using the built in `str.format` method:

```
"<\\{}/>".format(a)
"<\\{} {}/>".format(a, b)
"<\\{1} {0}/>".format(a, b)  # => "<\\" + b + " " + a + "/>"
"<\\{a} {b}/>".format(a=a, b=b)
```

Comment: "Python 3.x style" works in 2.6+, so it's not really 3.x style

Comment: @Blender: afaik the feature was introduced in and backported to 2.x from 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `str.format` method:

```
a = "Hello {name}, welcome to {place}."
a.format(name="Salem", place="Tokyo")  # "Hello Salem, welcome to Tokyo."
```

[docs.python.org - String format syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

If you need something more powerful, you can use a template engine. There is a quick example with [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/):

- jinja_example.py

  ```
  from jinja2 import Template

  template_file = Template(open("templatefile").read())

  obj = [
      {"name": "John", "surname": "Doe"},
      {"name": "Foo", "surname": "Bar"}
  ]

  print template_file.render(data=obj)
  ```
- templatefile

  ```
  <html>
  <body>
  {% if data %}
      {% for user in data %}
      <h1>Hello {{ user.name }} {{ user.surname }}.</h1>
      {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
      <h1>Nothing found.</h1>
  {% endif %}
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

And the output (some newline's removed):

```
$ python jinja_example.py
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello John Doe.</h1>    
    <h1>Hello Foo Bar.</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

You can find a huge list of template engines in [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating).

Comment: Python uses '#' for comments instead of '//' .